# How to implement Token based Rest API in android App

Tags: java, android, api, oauth-2.0, access-token

I want to use Http Restful token Based api in my App, But it gives me data when i send **ACCESS KEY, SECRET KEY, APP_ID, DEVICE_ID** in postman . I am confused that is this a oAuth2 or not. How to implement this API in Android app. I watched a lot of videos in youtube about oAuth 2 and token based api but its not working for me. The JSON is coming something like this when we send request.

```
{"status":true,"version":"2.0.2","status_code":200,"expires":"-1",
"auth":{"access_token":"2s153415154217785s1031898106557579455","expires":"1534858655.0"},
"Etag":null,"cache_key":"auth|2s153415154217785s1031898106557579455|http://192.167.41.180:4000/|"}
```

and when we send token with desired api link 
https://rest.cricketapi.com/rest/v2/kabaddi/season/pkl_2017/recent_matches/?access_token=2s153415154217785s1031898106557579455

it show like this

```
{
    "Etag": "1534772423.0",
    "cache_key": "kabaddi|recent_matches|pkl_2017|micro_card",
    "data": {
        "card_type": "micro_card",
        "cards": [
            {
                "cache_key": "kabaddi|match|pkl_2017_final|micro_card",
                "expires": "1534772423.0",
                "group": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_final",
                    "name": "Final"
                },
                "key": "pkl_2017_final",
                "name": "GUJARAT FORTUNEGIANTS vs PATNA PIRATES",
                "result": {
                    "str": "PATNA PIRATES won the match",
                    "winner_team": "b"
                },
                "round": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_final",
                    "name": "Final"
                },
                "season": {
                    "competition": {
                        "key": "pkl_2017",
                        "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017"
                    },
                    "key": "pkl_2017",
                    "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017",
                    "short_name": "PK 17"
                },
                "start_date": {
                    "iso": "2017-10-28T14:30+00:00",
                    "str": "28th Oct 2017 14:30 GMT",
                    "timestamp": "1509201000"
                },
                "status": "completed",
                "sub_card_name": "Final",
                "teams": {
                    "a": {
                        "key": "guj_fort",
                        "name": "GUJARAT FORTUNEGIANTS",
                        "short_name": "GF"
                    },
                    "b": {
                        "key": "pat_pirates",
                        "name": "PATNA PIRATES",
                        "short_name": "PP"
                    }
                },
                "venue": {
                    "name": "Chennai"
                }
            },
            {
                "cache_key": "kabaddi|match|pkl_2017_e2|micro_card",
                "expires": "1534772424.0",
                "group": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_e",
                    "name": "Eliminator"
                },
                "key": "pkl_2017_e2",
                "name": "BENGAL WARRIORS vs PATNA PIRATES",
                "result": {
                    "str": "PATNA PIRATES won the match",
                    "winner_team": "b"
                },
                "round": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_e",
                    "name": "Eliminator"
                },
                "season": {
                    "competition": {
                        "key": "pkl_2017",
                        "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017"
                    },
                    "key": "pkl_2017",
                    "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017",
                    "short_name": "PK 17"
                },
                "start_date": {
                    "iso": "2017-10-26T14:30+00:00",
                    "str": "26th Oct 2017 14:30 GMT",
                    "timestamp": "1509028200"
                },
                "status": "completed",
                "sub_card_name": "Qualifier 2",
                "teams": {
                    "a": {
                        "key": "ben_warriors",
                        "name": "BENGAL WARRIORS",
                        "short_name": "BW"
                    },
                    "b": {
                        "key": "pat_pirates",
                        "name": "PATNA PIRATES",
                        "short_name": "PP"
                    }
                },
                "venue": {
                    "name": "Chennai"
                }
            },
            {
                "cache_key": "kabaddi|match|pkl_2017_e1|micro_card",
                "expires": "1534772424.0",
                "group": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_e",
                    "name": "Eliminator"
                },
                "key": "pkl_2017_e1",
                "name": "PUNERI PALTAN vs PATNA PIRATES",
                "result": {
                    "str": "PATNA PIRATES won the match",
                    "winner_team": "b"
                },
                "round": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_e",
                    "name": "Eliminator"
                },
                "season": {
                    "competition": {
                        "key": "pkl_2017",
                        "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017"
                    },
                    "key": "pkl_2017",
                    "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017",
                    "short_name": "PK 17"
                },
                "start_date": {
                    "iso": "2017-10-24T15:30+00:00",
                    "str": "24th Oct 2017 15:30 GMT",
                    "timestamp": "1508859000"
                },
                "status": "completed",
                "sub_card_name": "Eliminator 3",
                "teams": {
                    "a": {
                        "key": "pune_paltan",
                        "name": "PUNERI PALTAN",
                        "short_name": "PUP"
                    },
                    "b": {
                        "key": "pat_pirates",
                        "name": "PATNA PIRATES",
                        "short_name": "PP"
                    }
                },
                "venue": {
                    "name": "Mumbai"
                }
            },
            {
                "cache_key": "kabaddi|match|pkl_2017_q3|micro_card",
                "expires": "1534772424.0",
                "group": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_q",
                    "name": "Qualifier"
                },
                "key": "pkl_2017_q3",
                "name": "GUJARAT FORTUNEGIANTS vs BENGAL WARRIORS",
                "result": {
                    "str": "GUJARAT FORTUNEGIANTS won the match",
                    "winner_team": "a"
                },
                "round": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_q",
                    "name": "Qualifier"
                },
                "season": {
                    "competition": {
                        "key": "pkl_2017",
                        "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017"
                    },
                    "key": "pkl_2017",
                    "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017",
                    "short_name": "PK 17"
                },
                "start_date": {
                    "iso": "2017-10-24T14:30+00:00",
                    "str": "24th Oct 2017 14:30 GMT",
                    "timestamp": "1508855400"
                },
                "status": "completed",
                "sub_card_name": "Qualifier 1",
                "teams": {
                    "a": {
                        "key": "guj_fort",
                        "name": "GUJARAT FORTUNEGIANTS",
                        "short_name": "GF"
                    },
                    "b": {
                        "key": "ben_warriors",
                        "name": "BENGAL WARRIORS",
                        "short_name": "BW"
                    }
                },
                "venue": {
                    "name": "Mumbai"
                }
            },
            {
                "cache_key": "kabaddi|match|pkl_2017_q2|micro_card",
                "expires": "1534772424.0",
                "group": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_q",
                    "name": "Qualifier"
                },
                "key": "pkl_2017_q2",
                "name": "PATNA PIRATES vs HARYANA STEELERS",
                "result": {
                    "str": "PATNA PIRATES won the match",
                    "winner_team": "a"
                },
                "round": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_q",
                    "name": "Qualifier"
                },
                "season": {
                    "competition": {
                        "key": "pkl_2017",
                        "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017"
                    },
                    "key": "pkl_2017",
                    "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017",
                    "short_name": "PK 17"
                },
                "start_date": {
                    "iso": "2017-10-23T15:30+00:00",
                    "str": "23rd Oct 2017 15:30 GMT",
                    "timestamp": "1508772600"
                },
                "status": "completed",
                "sub_card_name": "Eliminator 2",
                "teams": {
                    "a": {
                        "key": "pat_pirates",
                        "name": "PATNA PIRATES",
                        "short_name": "PP"
                    },
                    "b": {
                        "key": "har_steelers",
                        "name": "HARYANA STEELERS",
                        "short_name": "HS"
                    }
                },
                "venue": {
                    "name": "Mumbai"
                }
            },
            {
                "cache_key": "kabaddi|match|pkl_2017_q1|micro_card",
                "expires": "1534772424.0",
                "group": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_q",
                    "name": "Qualifier"
                },
                "key": "pkl_2017_q1",
                "name": "PUNERI PALTAN vs U.P. YODDHA",
                "result": {
                    "str": "PUNERI PALTAN won the match",
                    "winner_team": "a"
                },
                "round": {
                    "key": "pkl_2017_q",
                    "name": "Qualifier"
                },
                "season": {
                    "competition": {
                        "key": "pkl_2017",
                        "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017"
                    },
                    "key": "pkl_2017",
                    "name": "Pro Kabaddi 2017",
                    "short_name": "PK 17"
                },
                "start_date": {
                    "iso": "2017-10-23T14:30+00:00",
                    "str": "23rd Oct 2017 14:30 GMT",
                    "timestamp": "1508769000"
                },
                "status": "completed",
                "sub_card_name": "Eliminator 1",
                "teams": {
                    "a": {
                        "key": "pune_paltan",
                        "name": "PUNERI PALTAN",
                        "short_name": "PUP"
                    },
                    "b": {
                        "key": "up_yoddha",
                        "name": "U.P. YODDHA",
                        "short_name": "UPY"
                    }
                },
                "venue": {
                    "name": "Mumbai"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "expires": "1534772423.0",
    "status": true,
    "status_code": 200,
    "version": "2.0.3"
}
```

I want to implement in my Android application. But its not getting data  in android app after using retrofit token based authentication and oAuth 2. Please Help me guys.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I'm working with Rest Api in my application, this technology is used on the server, and you need to communicate with the api using the libraries in the application. For my development, I used Retrofit, in my opinion this is the most flexible library for working with Rest Api on android. So there is a library like Volley. The bottom line is simple, you have to send the key to the server to access the information that you need, and in order for something to send you need to get this key. The developers of the server part should give you the documentation. Maybe my answer will help you.